# Is there any GLL parser combinator library in C# / Java?

Tags: java, .net, parsing, parser-combinators, superpower

I'm really interested in parser combinators, especially those who can deal with left-recursive and ambiguous grammars. I know the fabulous [Superpower](https://github.com/datalust/superpower) by [Nicholas Blumhardt](https://github.com/nblumhardt) but it's unable to deal with this kind of grammars.

I've found some GLL parser combinators libraries like this https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators, but it uses Scala and, that is a big inconvenience for me (I don't know that language).

I would like to know if there is any of these in C# (or Java)

Comment: Did you see ANTLR 4?? https://www.antlr.org/

Comment: ANTLR 4 has the ability to deal with left-recursive and ambiguous grammars, as I remember, I read the book, and you can implement the parser with c# and Java, I did work with java. Also, they offer starter grammars on their GitHub.